# Pop up not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

```html
<li>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">settings</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Settings</h4> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="#" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="setting_name" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Setting Name</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="text" maxlength="25" class="form-control" id="setting_name" name="setting_name" placeholder="Setting Name" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="setting_value" class="col-lg-4 control-label">Setting Value</label>
              <div class="col-lg-8">
                <input type="int" maxlength="10" class="form-control" id="setting_value" name="setting_value" placeholder="Setting Value" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Send</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                <button type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-info">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Whenever I fire this the pop up doesn't work .Just the screen gets faded and nothing happens then I have to refresh it.

Comment: would post your code ? or a demo better ??

Comment: I've edited your post into shape. Before you continue please take your time to head to the [tour] and read [ask]. Also the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) will be of benefit if you want to get the most out of your questions and this community of volunteers.